# How to properly flip a somewhat complex 2D character?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok, so I have this little barbarian dude I purchased in a big pack of assets from GameDevMarket.  I'm scripting his movement and I've ran into a snag that I can't figure out how to get past.  Basically when he moves left I want him to turn around, but none of the approaches I can think of are working properly.

First, when I try to rotate him 180 degrees with Quaternion(0,180,0,0) or (0,-180,0,0) or even (180,0,180,0) I get the sprites being all out of order as so:
[image]

When I cycle through all the children components, get all the sprite renderers and set "flipX", I get this nonsense:
[image]

Anybody have an idea of what's going on here, and how I can get beyond it and flip my lil' dude properly?

Comment: rotate y-axis by 180º

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it'll work for nested sprites, but you could try flipping the X scale to -1. You should only need to do this for the parent-most sprite, not each sprite.

Comment: You're a f*cking genius...  Or I'm way more of a noob than I thought I was.  Both are equally plausible...  I'm gonna go with you're a genius.

Works perfectly, thank you very much!  Definitely taught me something new.

Comment: No problem! It's a super simple solution but works quite well in most cases. If that answered the question, would you mind marking it answered?

Comment: Keep in mind if you go this route, your meshes wont be batched and you'll take a performance hit on all draw calls (Unity doesn't batch any meshes under a negatively scaled transform).  We use a script that caches the z-ordering of the pieces of characters on `Awake()`. When we flip them, we reverse the z-ordering and rotate on the y-axis by 180 degrees.  (I'm still upvoting this answer, btw)

Comment: Also, @Ace you can choose to [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) since it has worked for you; it'll give some extra credit to the answer-er for helping you out ;]